# Random strings from a list of strings

Tags: perl, awk

I have a list of strings, I want to pick up strings from that list randomly. Could you anyone help me out with perl or awk.

String List:

```
John
Peter
Adam
Mike
Charlie
Sanders
William
...
```

Output:

```
Peter
Mike
Sanders
...
```

Comment: Are you on Linux? There's `sort --random-sort ...`

Comment: @mob seriously? Cool .. didn't know that, stored away for future use.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I need to pick certain number of random strings from the list. For example, I have a list of 5000 strings, I want to pick-up 500 random string from the list of 5000.

Comment: @DSM: `shuf -n 500 words.txt`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: even better!

Comment: @Kaartz: Is your list in a file or do you have it in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have those names in a file.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
print for (shuffle read_file 'the_input_file_name' )[0..499];
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) module provides a `shuffle` operator. It is also a core module and so shouldn't need installing

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

open my $fh, '<', 'string_list.txt' or die $!;
my @names = <$fh>;

print for (shuffle @names)[0..499];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with your words, a new word on each line. Then run this script to pick a selected number (example below is showing 5) of the words out of the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

sub random_words {
$random_items = $_[0];

open(DB, 'random-words.db');
@words = <DB>;
close DB;

    for ($i=0; $i < $random_items; $i++) {
        $random_index = int(rand(@words));
        $random_word = $words[$random_index];
        $random_word =~ s/\R//g;
        print $random_word;
    }
}

random_words(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print splice(@a,rand(@a),1),"\n" while @a;
```

where @a our list g.e. 
my @a = qw/
John
Peter
Adam
Mike
Charlie
Sanders
William
/;